Seeking Intuitive Explanation for the Identity $a^{\log_b(c)} = c^{\log_b(a)}$**
I've been working through some logarithmic identities, and I've stumbled upon one that I find quite intriguing. While I know the algebraic proof for the identity $ a^{\log_b(c)} = c^{\log_b(a)} $, I'm looking for a deeper, intuitive understanding of why it holds true.
To give a bit of context, I understand the proof, which is usually shown like this:

We start with the definition of a logarithm: if $\log_b(x) = y$, then it must be true that $b^y = x$.
Applying this to $\log_b(c)$, we have $b^{\log_b(c)} = c$.
If we then raise $a$ to the power of $\log_b(c)$, we get $a^{\log_b(c)} = a^{(\log_b(c))}$.
By the properties of exponents, this can be rewritten as $(b^{\log_b(a)})^{\log_b(c)}$.
Since we know that $b^{\log_b(a)} = a$, this simplifies to $a^{\log_b(c)} = (b^{\log_b(a)})^{\log_b(c)} = c^{\log_b(a)}$.

However, I'm still looking for that intuitive clarity. When I see the expression $a^{\log_b(c)}$, I think of it as "raising $a$ to the power that you would raise $b$ to get $c$." Conversely, when I see $c^{\log_b(a)}$, it seems to be "raising $c$ to the power that you would raise $b$ to get $a$." Intuitively, it's not immediately obvious to me why raising a number to the 'log power' of two different numbers would result in the same value.
Could anyone help me develop an intuition or provide a different perspective that might illuminate why this identity is true?

To provide insight, may I know what is the type of proof that would make $\left(b^A\right)^C = \left(b^C\right)^A$, an exponent law, intuitive to you?

$\log_b c = x$ is an exponent to which $b$ must be raised in order to equal $c$; i.e., $b^x = c$.
Similarly, $\log_b a = y$ is an exponent to which $b$ must be raised in order to equal $a$; i.e., $b^y = a$.
Thus, $a^{\log_b c} = a^x$ and $c^{\log_b a} = c^y$ are equal, because
$$a^x = (b^y)^x = (b^x)^y = c^y.$$
